# How to compare lists using sets to find the difference in Async environment? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

So currently I have two strings where I turn into lists and compare them by turning them into sets using these functions.

```
def add_compare(File1, File2):
    d = set(File1.splitlines())
    e = set(File2.splitlines())
    a = list(e - d)
    return a


def remove_compare(File1, File2):
    d = set(File1.splitlines())
    e = set(File2.splitlines())
    a = list(d - e)
    return a

added = add_compare(f1, f2)
removed = remove_compare(f1, f2)
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 239, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 100, in uS
    added = await add_compare(f1, f2)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 66, in add_compare
    a = list(e - d)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'coroutine' and 'coroutine'
```

I'm using discord.py with MyClient(commands.Bot). It didn't break until I changed it to commands.Bot. It used to be discord.Client. Not sure if this change is what caused it to break. So how do I get it to return a list again instead of coroutines?

Comment: The builtin `set` function was probably shadowed by an async function of the same name.

Comment: @MichaelButscher OH you're so right. I forgot I had created a discord command using "set." Thanks so much.